# SpringBoot could not access ElasticSearch on kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

Spring Boot access ElasticSearch Problem on kubernetes Problem

If ElasticSearch installed locally then Spring Boot Application can access it via spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300

But when both of them installed on K8s, SpringBoot could not access it anymore

the deployment yaml of spring boot is like below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springbootelastic
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: springbootelastic
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: springbootelastic
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: springbootelastic
          image: wangyan100/springbootelastic:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: CLUSTER_NODES
              value: elasticsearch:9300
            - name: CLUSTER_HOST
              value: elasticsearch
      #imagePullSecrets:
      #  - name: regcred
```

all yaml files and code you could find it at 
https://github.com/wangyan100/springbootexamples/tree/master/spring-boot-elasticsearch/src

The exception I got at spring boot 's pod log is as below shown

: Adding transport node : 10.108.175.123:9300 not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch], ignoring...

: failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{RwIDGzHOQFqU1Lrl0yULkQ}{elasticsearch}{10.108.175.123:9300}]

elasticsearch running on pod, I could browser it via http://192.168.99.113:31183 (31183 is nodeport )

```
{
  "name" : "c97xU38",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "3FQq0XXeQjuzDRqXO2wY6w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.4.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "fe40335",
    "build_date" : "2018-10-30T23:17:19.084789Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: You do not seem to be accessing this environment variable anywhere in the code CLUSTER_NODES ? localhost works because thats what you have in your props file.

Comment: Can you post the output of http://elasticsearch:9200, you should see something like this {

    "name": "5M3kvCf",
    "cluster_name": "docker-cluster",
    "cluster_uuid": "tbbXSaIIQhearMZckxpEQQ",
    "version": {
        "number": "6.2.4",
        "build_hash": "ccec39f",
        "build_date": "2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "7.2.1",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "5.6.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"

}

Comment: Using yaml file, CLUSTER_NODES 's value is elasticsearch:9300
elasticsearch is elasticsearch's servicename running on k8s pod, on k8s , pods can use service:port to communicate with each other instead of ip:port

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. I wrote it [at this link](https://github.com/wangyan100/springbootexamples/tree/master/spring-boot-k8s).

#### Deploy SpringBootApplication and ElasticSearch on Kubernetes

This demo will show you how to deploy SpringBootApplication and ElasticSearch on Kubernetes.

The demo will use the SpringBootApplication from [this link](https://github.com/wangyan100/springbootexamples/tree/master/spring-boot-elasticsearch).

**Build docker image**

- gradle clean build
- docker build -t wangyan100/springbootelastic .

**Push docker image (wangyan100/springbootelastic) to docker hub**

- create wangyan100/springbootelastic as repository at Docker Hub website. Of course, you need register an account at Docker Hub website if you don't have one.
- docker login
- enter docker hub's username and password.
- docker tag <image_id> wangyan100/springbootelastic:latest
- docker push wangyan100/springbootelastic:latest

**Write deployment and service yaml files**

- for SpringBootApplication, you could find example as shown below.

  [image: 1]
- for elasticsearch, you could find example as shown below.

  [image: 2]

**Install Kubernetes on your local machine**

- Follow [the link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) to install Kubernetes on your local PC.

**Deploy Application on Kubernetes**

- minikube start --memory 4096 (elasticsearch requires 4GB memory).
- Deploy elasticsearch.

  ```
  cd spring-boot-elasticsearch/src/elastick8s
  kubectl apply -f .
  ```
- Wait until elasticsearch is up and running.

  ```
  kubectl get pods
  NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   
  elasticsearch-5b74bbdd86-wgw2n       1/1     Running   0
  ```
- Deploy SpringBootApplication.

  ```
  cd spring-boot-elasticsearch/src/springbootk8s
  kubectl apply -f .
  ```
- Get exposed URL of springboot and elasticsearch.

  ```
  minikube service springbootelastic --url
  http://192.168.99.113:31742

  minikube service elasticsearch --url
  http://192.168.99.113:30765
  http://192.168.99.113:32663
  ```
- Use postman to send request to SpringBootApplication, it will create an entry at elasticsearch.

  [image: 3]
- Check result, it works.

  [image: 4]

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the output of http://elasticsearch:9200, you should see something like this:

```
{

    "name": "5M3kvCf",
    "cluster_name": "docker-cluster",
    "cluster_uuid": "tbbXSaIIQhearMZckxpEQQ",
    "version": {
        "number": "6.2.4",
        "build_hash": "ccec39f",
        "build_date": "2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "7.2.1",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "5.6.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

The cluster name should match with:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name
```

in your spring configuration.

Comment: when it is running on k8s pod, you could access it via below URL http://192.168.99.113:31183